# Issue during fetch the struct to get the result [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am saving the needed information that I got from an HTTP request to a structure and trying to save it into the local storage, but when I try to get the local storage item and print one value inside the struct it does not work!

My code as following:

```
//The response result I got from Http request.
.then(function(response) {

    //Save the needed UserInformation into struct.
    let CurrentUser = {
       username: response.data.result.User.username,
       name: response.data.result.User.name,
       token: response.data.result.token,
       id: response.data.result.User.id,
     }

    //Save the user information into the local storage.
    localStorage.setItem("CurrentUser", JSON.stringify(CurrentUser));
    var Curr_user = localStorage.getItem("CurrentUser");
    console.log(Curr_user);
    console.log("the name of the current user: " + Curr_user['name']);

})
```

The result I got as follows:

```
{"username":"Myusername","name":"Myname","token":"XXXXXX","id":"YYYYYY"}
the name of the current user: undefined
```

I want to get the username or id from the local storage, because I need them in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` stores everything as string, so you'll need to parse this JSON string before acessing it as an object.

This line:

```
localStorage.setItem("CurrentUser", JSON.stringify(CurrentUser));
var Curr_user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CurrentUser"));
```